# returning the name of the column with the boolean value 0

Tags: mysql, boolean, tinyint

I want to query the table below as to return the titles of the column where the intersection of SessionId and Roomx is 0.The type of the Room is TINYINT - which in mysql represents BOOLEAN

Below is the table:

```
SessionId    Room1    Room2    Room3
    1          0        1        0  
    2          1        0        1
```

For the above table for example for SessionId 1 , query should return Room1 and Room3
Help will be much  appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like application logic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a table in need of a redesign.  Judging by the column names, the "objects" (rows) you should be dealing with are "Events":  An Event happens *in* a Room, *during* a section.  With that setup, your table would look like:

```
session_id room_id
1          2
2          1
2          3
```

Now there's still not a query that'll give you the rooms that *aren't* in use during a given session, but it's easy to find the ones that *are:*

```
SELECT room_id FROM events WHERE session_id = <whatever>
```

And it's easy to combine that with a list of all possible rooms to get the information you need.

Hope this helps!

**PS:**  If you have a `rooms` table as well (I wouldn't add one just for this, but if you happened to have one), it gets even easier:

```
SELECT id FROM rooms WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM events WHERE room_id = id AND session_id = <whatever>)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tabel Name'
```

Comment: @Dan Grossman Thanks but what do you mean by application logic? @Poonam Bhatt not quite

Comment: Logic that belongs in your program's code, not in a database query.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I will look at the lproblem differently and see if I can return the same using application logic.